# CoordinatorLayout No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am trying to add a relative layout inside of a Coordinator Layout but continuously getting the error **No drawer view found with gravity LEFT** can some one help me to fix this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    android:gravity="left">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cover"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/sidebar_menu" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Error Stack**

```
05-04 19:00:35.073 14889-14889/sathyabaman.com.coolwallpapers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sathyabaman.com.coolwallpapers, PID: 14889
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1651)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1637)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.toggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:294)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.onClick(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:203)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

can some one help me to fix this issue. tnx

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you set up the navigation drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:gravity="left"` is not a valid attribute for `DrawerLayout`.

You need to change `tools:openDrawer="end"` to `tools:openDrawer="start"` for your `DrawerLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="end"` to `android:layout_gravity="start"` for your `NavigationView`.

---

The above solution works if you are opening the drawer with `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);` or `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`.

If you want it to open from the right-hand side you may keep your XML as it is and change the way you open the drawer to `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.END);` or `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a gravity=left in your DrawerLayout either.

Add `android:gravity="left"` to your DrawerLayout.